# How to rotate a 3D vector on the surface of a plane by a known angle?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors

### Available data

1. The plane β which is defined by a normal vector n and point P.
2. The vector v which lies on the surface of the plane.(the angle between v and n is 90 degrees).
3. The angle α to which v should be rotated.

---

How to obtain the rotated vector(vrot) ?

Note that the vectors are 3D.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1514364/find-the-vector-in-the-new-position-obtained-by-rotation). It will help. :)

Comment: It did help, in the sense that i have a clearer idea, but i don't understand what l in Rodrigues' rotation formula would be in this case.                           Is l = (v x n) / (||v x n||) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $v \neq 0$ and $n$ is a *unit* vector, the vectors $v$ and $n \times v$ are an orthogonal basis of your plane, and the result of rotating $v$ counterclockwise (about $n$) by an angle $\alpha$ is
$$
(\cos\alpha)\, v + (\sin\alpha)\, (n \times v).
$$

Comment: Hi @Andrew, is there any this is possible without $n$, I mean asper my question here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4386389/585488